# Div container disappears when resizing window vertically

Tags: css

I have a weird question, why is it that when I resize my window vertically my div container shrinks/disappears and does not follow the normal website layout. Here is a screenshot to what I am talking about.

[image]

As you can see, the red should be covering all the content, including that box with all the colors inside. This only occurs when I resize my webpage vertically, I cannot figure out why it does this.

Here is my code:

```css
.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100% - 84px);
}

.main-content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.info-box-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.info-box {
  display: flex;
  height: 195px;
  width: 350px;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.info-box .left-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

.info-box .top {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: yellow;
}

.info-box .top p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: green;
  font-size: 25px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.info-box .bottom {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: orange;
}

.info-box .right-side {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.info-box:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.welcome-msg {
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}

.welcome-msg p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="main-content-container">
    <div class="welcome-msg">
      <p>Welcome, Omar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info-box-container">
      <div class="info-box">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="top">
            <p>500</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom">
            <p>Reports</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `height: calc(100% - 84px);` This is the reason I guess

Comment: @samuellawrentz But without that when my window is in full screen the container size won't fit the entire screen.

Comment: If you are not supporting old browsers. You could try `height: 100vh;`

Comment: @samuellawrentz 100vh would not account for the space already taken by the nav-bar and the margin underneath the nav-bar either hence why I used the calc function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `min-height` to the `.main-content`. In your case the `.info-box` is `195px` in height. Set the `min-height` of the `.main-content` to `195px` so that when you resize the screen it does not shrink beyond `195px`, that is the size of the `.info-box`.

https://codepen.io/samuellawrentz/pen/wxKRga

```css
.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100% - 84px);
  min-height: 195px;
}

.main-content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.info-box-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.info-box {
  display: flex;
  height: 195px;
  width: 350px;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.info-box .left-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

.info-box .top {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: yellow;
}

.info-box .top p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: green;
  font-size: 25px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.info-box .bottom {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: orange;
}

.info-box .right-side {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.info-box:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.welcome-msg {
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}

.welcome-msg p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="main-content-container">
    <div class="welcome-msg">
      <p>Welcome, Omar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info-box-container">
      <div class="info-box">
        <div class="left-side">
          <div class="top">
            <p>500</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom">
            <p>Reports</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good idea. But how will I center the content vertically? Keep in mind there is also "welcome-msg" div that I need to center vertically as well. If I set a min-height on the main-content div won't it affect it when I view the page in full-screen mode?

Comment: @OmarDajani Please mention these requirements in the question as well. Also, I'm not sure what your case is. Check out this codepen https://codepen.io/samuellawrentz/pen/wxKRga

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Sorry I was not clear at the beginning.